# javascript causing 2nd pop up window to occur?

Tags: javascript

I'm using this javascript once a user has clicked submit on a html form. What I am trying to achieve is have a jquery window pop up. However, whilst it does do this, the browser is also opening up a new _blank target window at the same time and I don't want it to do this.

Is there a way to stop this so I only have the one jquery "shadowbox" window coming up?.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myform').submit(function() {
            Shadowbox.open({
            content:    '<iframe src="loginin.php" width="500" height="300" scrolling="no" style="overflow:hidden; border:none;"></iframe>',
            player:     "html",
            height:     300,
            width:      500
        });

        this.target = 'formpopup';
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting `this.target = "formpopup"` is telling the form to submit to a new window/tab named "formpopup". Remove that line, and cancel the event instead.

Comment: ok but when i take that line away it won't bring up the query pop up window and just links to the page in the parent window. how can i cancel the event?

Comment: I don't know how you do it in jQuery and can't be arsed to look it up. Most likely you have `e` as the first parameter to your function and call `e.preventDefault()`